# Finding the truth

Tags: meditation

I have been meditating for a month it happens because i needed to find truth and what is the real happiness.i am meditating 20 minutes(15-20) three times a day . I always thinking while meditating if i have any kusal(merit) please show me the path of truth.recently when meditating i feel only body  exists every feeling in only on body.it is like controlling a robo(body) while on it. It was very hard to explain, but now i need to go out on my body and find what im searching . can anyone please explain something about  this

Actually, what i am saying is that true happiness is  now. im too tired of my life every time i saw reality. Everything make me sad , and everything is temporary.

Comment: Bro you need to take a break it's burnout, I also feel like that sometimes, I prefer to travel or spend time with my friends to get over it. I think Meditation may worsen the situation, there is a state called trans people tend to behave like they are messenger of God in such state, they may even walk on burning coal , our mind is complex bio computer so it may create false experiences don't fall in this trap of spirituality, how can you find truth if you are not ok? if you want a quick fix Osho is a good guru it's your choice but I think you need him, may you be blessed 

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't related to Buddhism directly but I was in such situation and since I am too an undergrad I can understand that this phase is frustrating!

Our brain changes a alot from birth to adolescence, it grows in its size and in number of cells contained within. The human brain attains peak processing power and memory around age 18. After studying how intelligence changes over time, scientists found that participants in their late teens had the highest performance. Nonetheless, this age can be one of mood swings, sulking, a craving for privacy and short tempers. Young children are not able to think far ahead, but young teens can and do—which allows them to worry about the future.These changes don't stop once you turn 18 but it grows with time and may settle down once full maturity is attained. So our feelings are natural.

[This is great video](https://youtu.be/LKPwKFigF8U?feature=shared) to understand why we are uncomfortable while we aren't doing anything challenging. I was in same phase and still sometimes feel it but after consulting with a physician found out that everyone goes through it and it heals with time.

Meditation when performed correctly is good but I have left it after similar experiences as yours, Buddha's teachings are very helpful to live a moral life but Vipassana (done under experienced instructor) is great tool too. Personally, personalities like osho or j krishnamurti are also helpful since you can listen to them through video recordings whereas what you know about Buddha's orginal teachings is all third person narrative (it doesn't mean it's useless but we should be careful).

At last this site is not for this kind of answers but helping you was important, try to be ordinary finding joy in things like cooking with granny, taking uncle's dog on walk or just going on short trips with friends or solo has helped me instead of meditation and doing random pyschological experimentation. If your symptoms persist even after doing all this please consult with your physician tell it to your parents or friends but believe me it's just a illusion Truth is not found meditating!(and I have a solid argument for it)

This is piece  of J krishnamurti's book freedom from know it was eye opener for me that I was on wrong track which you too are.

> Man has throughout the ages been seeking something beyond himself,
> beyond material welfare - something we call truth or God or reality, a timeless
> state - something that cannot be disturbed by circumstances, by thought or by
> human corruption. Man has always asked the question: what is it all about? Has life any meaning
> at all? He sees the enormous confusion of life, the brutalities, the revolt, the wars,
> the endless divisions of religion, ideology and nationality, and with a sense of
> deep abiding frustration he asks, what is one to do, what is this thing we call
> living, is there anything beyond it?
> And not finding this nameless thing of a thousand names which he has always
> sought, he has cultivated faith - faith in a saviour or an ideal - and faith invariably
> breeds violence.

> One can see directly that it is only when the mind is silent that there is a
> possibility of clarity. The whole purpose of meditation in the East is to bring about
> such a state of mind - that is, to control thought, which is the same as constantly
> repeating a prayer to quieten the mind and in that state hoping to understand
> one's problems. But unless one lays the foundation, which is to be free from fear,
> free from sorrow, anxiety and all the traps one lays for oneself, I do not see how it
> is possible for a mind to be actually quiet. This is one of the most difficult things to
> communicate. Communication between us implies, doesn't it, that not only must
> you understand the words I am using but that we must both, you and I, be intense
> at the same time, not a moment later or a moment sooner and capable of
> meeting each other on the same level? And such communication is not possible
> when you are interpreting what you are reading according to your own
> knowledge, pleasure or opinions, or when you are making a tremendous effort to
> comprehend.

> That word had been used
> both in the East and the West in a most unfortunate way. There are different
> schools of meditation, different methods and systems. There are systems whichsay, `Watch the movement of your big toe, watch it, watch it, watch it; there are
> other systems which advocate sitting in a certain posture, breathing regularly or
> practising awareness. All this is utterly mechanical. The other method gives you a
> certain word and tells you that if you go on repeating it you will have some
> extraordinary transcendental experience. This is sheer nonsense. It is a form of
> self-hypnosis. By repeating Amen or Om or Coca-Cola indefinitely you will
> obviously have-a certain experience because by repeti- tion the mind becomes
> quiet. It is a well known phenomenon which has been practised for thousands of
> years in India - Mantra Yoga it is called. By repetition you can induce the mind to
> be gentle and soft but it is still a petty, shoddy, little mind.

> Meditation demands an astonishingly alert mind; meditation is the
> understanding of the totality of life in which every form of fragmentation has
> ceased. Meditation is not control of thought, for when thought is controlled it
> breeds conflict in the mind, but when you understand the structure and origin of
> thought, which we have already been into, then thought will not interfere.

> Meditation is not following any system; it is not constant repetition and
> imitation. Meditation is not concentration. It is one of the favourite gambits of
> some teachers of meditation to insist on their pupils learning concentration - that
> is, fixing the mind on one thought and driving out all other thoughts. This is a
> most stupid, ugly thing, which any schoolboy can do because he is forced to. It means that all the time you are having a battle between the insistence that you
> must concentrate on the one hand and your mind on the other which wanders
> away to all sorts of other things, whereas you should be attentive to every
> movement of the mind wherever it wanders. When your mind wanders off it
> means you are interested in something else.
> Meditation demands an astonishingly alert mind; meditation is the
> understanding of the totality of life in which every form of fragmentation has
> ceased. Meditation is not control of thought, for when thought is controlled it
> breeds conflict in the mind, but when you understand the structure and origin of
> thought, which we have already been into, then thought will not interfere.

It's not directly from Buddhism but it is great knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The meditation of the Buddha does not leave the body. The [Kayagata-sati Sutta: Mindfulness Immersed in the Body](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.119.than.html) is a sutta about the whole path. Again, in [AN 4.45](https://suttacentral.net/an4.45/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=sidenotes&highlight=false&script=latin), the Buddha said the whole path is within the body.

> For it is in this fathom-long carcass [body] with its perception and mind
> that I describe the world, its origin, its cessation and the practice [path]
> that leads to its cessation.
>
> [AN 4.45](https://suttacentral.net/an4.45/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=sidenotes&highlight=false&script=latin)

True happiness starts with the development of samatha (tranquility), which depends on keeping the mind within the body.

Answer (score 1):

> Everything make me sad, and everything is temporary.

We all have been there, sometimes I feel sad, too.

The only reason we are sad though, is because we expected it to be different. So it is our expectation that is wrong, not life.

If you keep running away from this, it will keep happening. It's only when you look at it straight in the face, and keep looking for a long time without much thinking, that's when it resolves.